# How to add child node without affecting layout of GridPane parent

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want create a app using javafx. It looks like this:

[image]

I want to add the zoom function for the chart. When I click the button "Zoom in", the app will become fig2. However, I have no idea to achieve it. When I change the size of pane included the chart, it will change grid pane size, looks like this:

[image: this]

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a zooming situation. I think you just need to change the height and width of you `Chart` when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want the zoom to be considered for the gridpane layout. In this can be achieved by applying transforms to the child of the gridpane you want to modify.

The following example demonstrates how to zoom a node while the mouse is hovering over it:

```
private static Region createRegion(String background) {
    Region region = new Region();
    region.setStyle("-fx-background-color:"+background);
    region.setPrefSize(300, 100);
    return region;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane gp = new GridPane();

    // create background
    gp.add(createRegion("green"), 0, 0);
    gp.add(createRegion("dodgerblue"), 0, 1);

    // create region to be zoomed
    Region zoomRegion = createRegion("red");
    GridPane.setFillWidth(zoomRegion, Boolean.FALSE);
    GridPane.setFillHeight(zoomRegion, Boolean.FALSE);
    zoomRegion.setPrefWidth(100);
    Scale scale = new Scale();
    zoomRegion.getTransforms().add(scale);

    // keep pivot at bottom left corner
    scale.pivotYProperty().bind(zoomRegion.heightProperty());

    zoomRegion.hoverProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        // adjust scale when hover state is changed
        double scaleFactor = newValue ? 1.5 : 1;
        scale.setX(scaleFactor);
        scale.setY(scaleFactor);
    });

    gp.add(zoomRegion, 0, 1);

    Scene scene = new Scene(gp);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well. But I meet another question. When I zoom in the chart, it will overlap with other chart. For example, befor I zoom in, it looks like [that](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B40SG6a0JJCER0FMRHE3M1h2dlk), after I zoom in, it looks like [that](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B40SG6a0JJCEbjVNMDFzYk5XaXc). I have set pane style `"-fx-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 1)"`